# Dynamic textboxes, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="#" id="AddMoreFileBox" class="btn btn-info">Add More Field</a>
<div id="InputsWrapper">
<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_1" value="Text 1"><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a></div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script type='Javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {

var MaxInputs       = 8; //maximum input boxes allowed
var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
var AddButton       = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID

var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added

$(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
{
        if(x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
        {
            FieldCount++; //text box added increment
            //add input box
            $(InputsWrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_'+ FieldCount +'" value="Text '+ FieldCount +'"/><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a></div>');
            x++; //text box increment
        }
return false;
});

$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        if( x > 1 ) {
                $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
                x--; //decrement textbox
        }
return false;
}) 

});

</script>
```

I found this on jfiddle. I tried it on my browser it won't add.

Is there any declaration like loading of a the library?

http://jsfiddle.net/LYDuZ/

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: See whats selected under **Frameworks & Extensions** on the left hand side bar of the demonstration window

Comment: Check your console, see if there are any errors

Comment: I lacked ,<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Its working now. Im using google chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to refer jquery in your code. Add this line in your head tag

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Was actually waiting for someone to give me this line of code.

I didnt know what website i needed to link for the library.

Comment: the distro is [here](http://jquery.com/download/). you can select one and copy the URL.

Comment: @user3205047 is that your problem?